# how perl array works $"

Tags: arrays, perl

I am confused about the outcome of this code.

```
my @lines;
for (my $count = 0; $count < 3; $count++) {

    print "Give me input again ";
    chomp (my $line = <STDIN>);
    $lines[$count] = $line;
}

$" = "|";
print "@lines\n";
```

When I run the code, how does this:  `$" = "|";` work?
The results are One|Two|Three. How does the code work so that it puts "|" between each input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$"` is just a special variable name in perl that tells the interpreter how to separate array elements in double-quoted string context.  The default value is a space, but the above code tells perl to use `|` instead.  Hence `One|Two|Three` instead of the default of `One Two Three` if you left out that line.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables for more detail.

Answer (score 8):

It's simply what interpolation of arrays into double-quoted strings does.

```
"$foo\n"
```

is identical to

```
$foo . "\n"
```

and

```
"@lines\n"
```

is identical to

```
join($", @lines) . "\n"
```

This is documented in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR).